# Android onSelectedDayChange works differently for different api level

Tags: android, calendarview

I use the `CalendarView` for save events, but it doesn't work for some devices!
It's graphical different (some devices need to scrool months and some devices have the arrow to the top of screen for change months).

But the main problem is that devices with the arrows to change month, the method `onSelectedDayChange` doesn't work (api level 23)!

This is the code that i use

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.CalendarView;


public class CalendarioActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    CalendarView calendar;
    Long date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendario);


        calendar = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        date = calendar.getDate();

        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                                            int dayOfMonth) {


                /*Con questo if blocco onSelectedDayChange quando viene scrollato
                il calendario per cambiare mese*/
                if(calendar.getDate() != date) {
                    date = calendar.getDate();
                   /* Quando seleziono un giorno apro l'activity per scriverci i compiti sopra*/
                    /*Passo tramite intent giorno,mese,anno*/
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalendarioActivity.this, ActivityEvento.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("day",dayOfMonth).putExtra("month", month+1).putExtra("year", year);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calendario, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.action_help:
                Intent aiuto_intent = new Intent(this, AiutoActivity.class);
                aiuto_intent.putExtra("chiamante", "calendario");
                startActivity(aiuto_intent);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the xml with the Calendar View

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ddz.diarioscolastico.CalendarioActivity">


    <CalendarView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:unfocusedMonthDateColor="@color/grigio_chiaro"
        android:dateTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:showWeekNumber="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The problem is the IF**

```
if(calendar.getDate() != date) {
   date = calendar.getDate();

   Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalendarioActivity.this,ActivityEvento.class); 
   myIntent.putExtra("day",dayOfMonth).putExtra("month", month+1).putExtra("year", year);
   startActivity(myIntent);

}
```

**For some api level (calendarview with arrow to the top for switch month), this `if` is always false and the intent doesn't start!**

Someone can tell me why?
Is there any way to make it work or some way for let the style of the `CalendarView` the same for all api version?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found any solution :(?

Comment: Now i post an answere so you can see how i solved the problem! Enjoy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution solved the problem for me!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calendario);


    calendar = (CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    date = calendar.getDate();

    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

            if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                // Do something for lollipop and above versions

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalendarioActivity.this, ActivityEvento.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("day",dayOfMonth).putExtra("month", month+1).putExtra("year", year);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            } else{
                // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop

                /*With this if i block onSelectedDayChange when the mounth change*/
                if(calendar.getDate() != date) {
                    date = calendar.getDate();

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalendarioActivity.this, ActivityEvento.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("day",dayOfMonth).putExtra("month", month+1).putExtra("year", year);
                    startActivity(myIntent);

                }
            }

        }
    });
}
```

As you can see here i check the version of the phone:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

                if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
                    // Do something for lollipop and above versions

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalendarioActivity.this, ActivityEvento.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("day",dayOfMonth).putExtra("month", month+1).putExtra("year", year);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                } else{
                    // do something for phones running an SDK before lollipop

                    /*Con questo if blocco onSelectedDayChange quando viene scrollato
                    il calendario per cambiare mese*/
                    if(calendar.getDate() != date) {
                        date = calendar.getDate();
                   /* Quando seleziono un giorno apro l'activity per scriverci i compiti sopra*/
                    /*Passo tramite intent giorno,mese,anno*/
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(CalendarioActivity.this, ActivityEvento.class);
                        myIntent.putExtra("day",dayOfMonth).putExtra("month", month+1).putExtra("year", year);
                        startActivity(myIntent);

                    }
                }
```

If the version is >= LOLLIPOP you just need the intent for take events and don't check if the user scroll the mounth (don't needed).
BUT if the version is < you need the else case!

Comment: Thanks for the response! <3

Comment: oh sorry for the italian comment! I forget to delete them!
Now i translate so who read can understand better the code! 
Enjoy!

Comment: I have lollipop and it still didn't work so I changed it to currentapiVersion > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP and it's working fine now.